# Java server. Multithread access to MySQL. How to manage multiple queries?

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, jdbc

I'm currently planning out a Java server that is running a thread pool that accepts client connections that will require that a database read/update occurs.

What about the case of multiple reads/writes on a single row? How should I manage this? Should I create a queue in Java or can MySQL handle this kind of stuff?

E.g. I plan on using transactions where I will use the following to lock a row:

```
Select <columns> from <table> where <condition> FOR UPDATE;
```

Question: What if another thread comes in and wants to update the same row before the first commits? Will the query fail or will MySQL hold it for a while and wait for the first lock to be release?

My current solution: I'm thinking a way to do it could be to create a static queue/pipe of all queries so that only one is fed to the DB at a time. This is obviously a bottleneck and general bad idea?

Also, are there any Java frameworks that handle this kind of thing and MySQL connections in general? Thanks.

EDIT: I am planning on using a threadpool so all queries will be coming from seperate connections.

Comment: Are the threads sharing a single DB connection, or does each thread get its own? If they're sharing, server-side locking won't work as MySQL won't be able to tell that it's two different threads pounding on the same link.

Comment: Before answering, a better understanding of what you want to accomplish would be essential: do you want threads hitting the same row to queue in line? Why do you want to lock the row at SELECT time instead of creating a lock when effectively updating? Why did you discard an optimistic locking approach?

Comment: I'm going to use a connection pool, so seperate connections.

Comment: @AlessandroSantini I don't know if want threads to queue in line. Not sure if it's needed. Is the SELECT FOR UPDATE method a good approach if I want to get the users account balance before I update?

Comment: I think this is what you need to figure out first. If you potentially have multiple threads updating the same account at the same time and you want to ensure that all updates are executed on a first-come, first-served basis, a SELECT FOR UPDATE potentially is what you are looking for.

If instead multiple threads hitting the same account may raise an error condition (e.g. update coming from a user interface with an outdated account balance displayed) a version column may be more effective.

Comment: Also, be very sure about your WHERE condition as on certain databases you may raise a lock escalation which means that page and table locking may be used instead of row.

Comment: So by version column you basically mean a semaphore stored in the table? Yes, I am aware of the table lock with incorrect WHERE but thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to worry about multiple threads reading or writing on the same row. MySQL will take care of that for you. Depending on the table engine, it will do it in a different manner, but it will always do it. If you have control over the tables, I recommend using the InnoDB engine, since it uses row-level locking. This way, it will handle much higher traffic. The (usual) alternative, however, (MyISAM) does not support row-level locking, it uses table locking.

Hope this helps.

PS:

> What if another thread comes in and wants to update the same row
>   before the first commits ?

MySQL keeps all `UPDATE`s and `INSERT`s in a buffer pool. When the pool gets big enough (or after a specific timeout occurs), the buffer is flushed to the tables. If a `SELECT` is executed before that flush, then MySQL will read information from both the buffer and the tables, in order to provide accurate information. **Exception to this: uncommitted transactions.**

Comment: What If I lock a row using Select <columns> from <table> where <condition> FOR UPDATE; and another thread tries to write to that row? Will the new write query still be buffered or will it just fail instantly?

Comment: @conor According to the MySQL Documentation, you cannot do a `SELECT FOR UPDATE` unless autocommit is disabled (either by setting it to 0 or by starting a transaction). To answer your question: if a `UPDATE` is issued on a row which is still locked by `SELECT FOR UPDATE`, then the `UPDATE` will wait until `SELECT FOR UPDATE` is completed and will execute after that.

Answer (score 0):

First off: Concurrent access has been handled for many decades by RDBMSs :)  MySQL will properly manage this for you as to not have to have you queue the requests.  There are however various concurrency (isolation) levels that you can set via JDBC.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setTransactionIsolation(int)

The big question in record concurrency is not so much the appropriate semantics, but user-level notification if the data is dirty.  BUT, if you simply need to ensure proper serial access to the record (row) nearly any DB will handle this beautifully.